# Java Jetty Memory Usage

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I am running a Jetty web server and using it to execute some bash scripts depending on what parameters it receives via GET. I've never worked with Jetty, so I pieced together some stuff [from here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/) to get it working. My issue is that it idles at ~100mb of ram when there are no requests, and after about 12 hours, it idles as high as 1gb of ram. This seems like an awful lot for something that just runs a bash script if the request is legit. The average file size that the servlet ends up serving is about 400kb.

How the server is started:

```
public void startServer() {

    String hostname = "localhost";
    int port        = 7500;

    Server server = new Server();

    Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setHost(hostname);
    connector.setPort(port);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});
    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new DaemonServlet()), "/call/*");

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { context });

    server.setHandler(handlers);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

The servlet (DaemonServlet):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String msg = "";

    String call = request.getParameter("call");
    ProcessBuilder pb = null;
    Process p = null;

    switch (call) {
    case "sendAction": // Sends an action to a process with a certain ID
        pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "/opt/test/process.sh", request.getParameter("process"), request.getParameter("action"));
        break;
    case "getFile": // Reads the file with the given ID into a string, to be returned by Jetty
        pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "/opt/test/getFile.sh", request.getParameter("fileId"));
        try {
            p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String scriptOutput = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                scriptOutput += line + '\n';
            }
            br.close();
            msg = scriptOutput;
            p.destroy();
            p = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        break;
    }

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().println(msg);
}
```

Is there anything that seems to be set up incorrectly here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line:

```
scriptOutput += line + '\n';
```

is consuming a huge amount of memory. Why not write the information back through the response as you get it?

Comment: Honestly didn't think about doing it that way, it would be better. Wouldn't GC take care of scriptOutput after that certain request is done though?

Comment: You have an open-ended String concatenation so you could potentially run out of memory before you have read all the output from getFile.sh process output.

Answer (score 0):

As Reimeus said, you should probably echo the output as you get it. If you go that way, you should send the response headers (content type, status code) **before** sending the process output.

At the very least, you should [use StringBuilder instead of concatenating Strings](http://jtechies.blogspot.com.ar/2012/07/item-51-beware-performance-of-string.html).